# fprintf in File not found

Tags: c

I have a problem in the fprintf in the function "menor" because the data is not visible in the file selected, i dont know what is the problem, please help, i think is the reference file, but not idea.

I have a problem in the fprintf in the function "menor" because the data is not visible in the file selected, i dont know what is the problem, please help, i think is the reference file, but not idea

```
    #include < stdio.h > 
    #include < stdlib.h > 
    #include < string.h >


    typedef struct {
        char * nombre;
        char * editorial;
        int valor;
        int area;
        int vendido;
    }
Libro;

int conteo(FILE * _entrada);
void datos(FILE * _entrada, Libro * _trabajo, int cantidad);
void menor(FILE * _entrada, FILE * _salida, Libro * _trabajo, int cantidad);

int main() {
    FILE * entrada;
    char ingreso[256];
    printf("Direccion del archivo de entrada \n");
    scanf("%255s", ingreso);
    entrada = fopen(ingreso, "r");
    if (entrada == NULL) {
        printf("No se pudo acceder al archivo de entrada \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE * salida;
    char final[256];
    printf("Direccion del archivo de salida \n");
    scanf("%255s", final);
    salida = fopen(final, "r");
    if (salida == NULL) {
        printf("No se pudo acceder al archivo de salida \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int cantidad = conteo(entrada);
    Libro * trabajo;
    trabajo = (Libro * ) malloc(sizeof(Libro) * cantidad);
    datos(entrada, trabajo, cantidad);
    menor(entrada, salida, trabajo, cantidad);
    return 0;
}

int conteo(FILE * _entrada) {
    char auxiliar1[100];
    int conteo = 0;
    while (!feof(_entrada)) {
        fgets(auxiliar1, 100, _entrada);
        conteo++;
    }
    rewind(_entrada);
    return (conteo / 5);
}

void datos(FILE * _entrada, Libro * _trabajo, int cantidad) {
    char auxiliar2[100];
    char * token;
    while (!feof(_entrada)) {
        fgets(auxiliar2, 100, _entrada);
        token = strtok(auxiliar2, ":");
        token = strtok(NULL, ":");
        (_trabajo - > nombre) = strdup(strtok(token, "\n"));

        fgets(auxiliar2, 100, _entrada);
        token = strtok(auxiliar2, ":");
        token = strtok(NULL, ":");
        (_trabajo - > editorial) = strdup(strtok(token, "\n"));

        fgets(auxiliar2, 100, _entrada);
        token = strtok(auxiliar2, ":");
        (_trabajo - > valor) = atoi(strtok(NULL, ":"));

        fgets(auxiliar2, 100, _entrada);
        token = strtok(auxiliar2, ":");
        (_trabajo - > area) = atoi(strtok(NULL, ":"));

        fgets(auxiliar2, 100, _entrada);
        token = strtok(auxiliar2, ":");
        (_trabajo - > vendido) = atoi(strtok(NULL, ":"));
    }
}




void menor(FILE * _entrada, FILE * _salida, Libro * _trabajo, int cantidad) {
    int i;
    int menor = 0;
    int posicion = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
        if ((_trabajo - > area) == 1) {
            menor = (_trabajo - > vendido);
            _trabajo++;
        }
    }
    _trabajo--;
    fprintf(_salida, "%s", (_trabajo - > nombre));
}
```

Comment: Please explain the error. Is it a runtime error, or a logic error. Also state the purpose of your code. That would help us to advise you further.

Comment: logic error, because when i create a FILE in the function "menor" he write correct but in this case, i need to create a FILE in the main because i need write in this FILE in another functions, but is not writting anything in the FILE

Answer (score 1):

In main, change:

```
salida = fopen(final, "r");
```

Into:

```
salida = fopen(final, "w");
```

This will truncate the file.  If you wanted to *update* the file (meaning change the existing file's contents without deleting it), you'd want "r+".

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the problem is vague. Please update your question to show us the exact (copy-and-pasted) error message.

But when I compile your program, I get:

```
c.c:1:26: fatal error:  stdio.h : No such file or directory
     #include < stdio.h > 
                          ^
compilation terminated.
```

Remove the spaces from the `#include` directives.  Change this:

```
#include < stdio.h > 
#include < stdlib.h > 
#include < string.h >
```

to this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
```

(The interpretation of the name between `<` and `>` is compiler-specific, but in this case the compiler is probably looking for a file whose name is literally `" stdio.h "`, including the leading and trailing spaces.)

Comment: The description is _not_ vague, nor is the solution.  The problem description is the first line of the post.  It means the program runs [_not_ a compile error] but the output file comes up empty.  BTW, OP did post the entire file.  The errors you were carping about are trivial to fix and SO isn't always perfect about formatting code samples.  See my answer--I'd did it with just code/desk inspection based on the first line of the post.  Your answer is _completely_ wrong, and OP clarified the real runtime problem in one of his comments _before_ your answer.

Comment: @CraigEstey: You may be correct, but I still find both the question and the comment vague. The first comment on the question asks "Is it a runtime error, or a logic error"; the OP replied that it's a "logic error". Does that mean the problem didn't occur at run time? I don't know. In any case, the OP needs to show the error message if there is one, or the program's output if there isn't. The extra spaces in the `#include` directive might indicate that the OP re-typed the code rather than copy-and-pasting it. If so, he needs to show us the actual code.

Comment: Cut OP slack (eng not 1st lang) and rewrite 1st sentence "file selected" to "file selected for output".  Prob 1st post and didn't know ctrl-k so he tried to post as html then edited back--I did that my first time, too.  Notice also "- >" instead of "->"--he did s/>/ >/g, etc.  code builds and runs with the minor typo fixes.  It is the real code.  And the program will prompt for two files and then run.  The output file will be empty and no error message comes out.  IMO, S/O's ctrl-k is braindamaged.  It also needs "paste from uploaded file"--might have prevented the typos